# Error Message in Community using visual force page - managed package Financialforce PSA

Tags: community, financialforce, currencytype, dlrs

Error Message in Community using visual force page - managed package Financialforce PSA:

> dlrs_pse_ExpenseTrigger: execution of AfterInsert caused by:
>   System.QueryException: sObject type 'CurrencyType' is not supported.
>   (dlrs)

I am getting the above error message when I am logging an expense in a custom salesforce community. This is preventing the user from being able to save the PSA Expense record as well as submit into a Salesforce Approval Process.

Would someone be able to point me in the right direction (other than contacting Financialforce support) as to how I might find out more about this error message I am receiving?

Answer (score 2):

The error is telling you that you appear to be using the Declarative Roll-up Summary Tool from Financial Force and also using multiple currencies. You must be doing a roll-up on something where the currency type varies or else are trying to roll up that object. I suspect the message is telling you that you can't do a roll-up on a field where the currency type varies. If your Community uses different currencies, that's going to be an issue for the Expense object that trigger is firing on. You'll need to convert to the correct currency before you can perform the roll-up.